# Displaying character at the x&y point

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I want to display a character at the X and Y position but nothing printing on the screen. My ASCII character is "9829". Any ideas?

```
 org 100h

MOV AX,0b800h
MOV ES,AX
MOV AX,poz_y
MOV BX,80
MUL BX
ADD AX,poz_x
MOV BX,2
MUL BX
MOV DI,AX
MOV [ES:DI],Word 9829h  


mov ax, 0x4c00
int 21h
poz_x dw 10
poz_y dw 10
```

Comment: [NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2), meaning you need to use `[poz_y]` and `[poz_x]`. Also, with my nasm it doesn't even assemble as-is, because of missing operand size for `MOV [ES:DI], 9829h` which should be `MOV WORD [ES:DI], 9829h `

Comment: Yeah, I know about `Word`, I just missed it here, sorry.

Comment: @Jester Okay, so with brackets its really working, thanks m8! :) Do you have any ideas how to put heart ascii here? Because I thought it was "9829h" but doesnt working, I must check :p.

Comment: `29h` = `)`. [Heart seems to be `03h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Codepage-437.png).

Comment: @Jester Thank you very much m8 :) It's working perfectly!

Comment: To multiply by power of two you can just shift left by the power. In your case \*2 is multiplying by first power of two, i.e. the whole offset calculation may go like: `..set es..` `mov ax,[poz_y]` `mov dx,80` `mov di,[poz_x]` `mul dx` `add di,ax` `shl di,1` `mov [es:di],word 9803h` (using also `dx` for \*80, because `mul` will modify `dx` any way, so there's no point to modify also `bx`). It is much less difficult for CPU to do `shl` instead of `mul` (it used to make difference in tens of clock cycles, nowadays the difference is minor, but still there).

Answer (score 0):

NASM requires that `poz_x` and `poz_y` be in brackets, like `[poz_x]`.

Without the brackets, it loads the *offset* of these variables into the register. The brackets cause the variable's address to be *dereferenced*, so that its *value* can be read.